# Is there a way to change device type on Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, htc, compatibility

I have an HTC One V, but I rooted it and installed CyMod 10.1. The problem I am currently facing is that the device shows up on Google Play as HTC One V which came with 4.0, whereas my phone now has 4.1.

Since it shows up as One V (4.0) many of the downloads show up as non-compatible with my phone and hence I cannot install them.

Is there any thing that can be done to remedy this?

Comment: I think you mean to say "it shows up as 4.1". Is that right?

Comment: @geffchang it doesn't is what i mean

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but try Market Helper: codekiem.com/2013/02/13/market-helper/ Please feedback if it works, so I can put it in as answer.

Comment: You need root to install Market Helper, BTW.

Comment: @geffchang I have altered my build.prop file already, so the job's done but you can answer with Market Helper because i am pretty sure it'll do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Market Helper](http://codekiem.com/2013/02/13/market-helper/); requires ROOT.

> Market Helper is a tool for Android that helps users to be able to
>   change/fake their rooted devices to any other devices. For example, it
>   can turn your Nexus 7 into Samsung Galaxy S3 in a few seconds. No
>   reboot is required.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to install apps from Google Play, you can download the apks directly using [APK Downloader](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/); all you'll need is the package name or Google Play URL. Then just move the files to your device and install normally.

As a One V owner as well, I recommend looking into [RhythmicRom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2147407). Google Play correctly detects my device as Android 4.2.2 and it's smooth and stable.